# Missing partial in gmaps4rails when called from a 'cell' renderer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, gmaps4rails, rails-cells

I'm using gem [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) and gem [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) both of which by themselves work brilliantly. However I've created a cell with haml

```
= gmaps(@options)
```

and I get the error

```
Missing partial /gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. 
Searched in:  * "/Users/bradphelan/workspace/openkitchen/app/cells"
```

the offending code is

```
----------------------
Google-Maps-for-Rails-75fc25d55f79/lib/gmaps4rails/helper/gmaps4rails_helper.rb
----------------------
 15   def gmaps(options, enable_css = true, enable_js = true )
 16     render :partial => 'gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails', :locals => { :options => options.with_indifferent_access, :enable_css => enable_css, :enable_js => enable_js }
 17   end
```

where the partial is rendered. This should work. The partial is there and it works when I call **gmaps** from a normal rails view template. Somehow **cells** is messing the partial search path and/or **gmaps** is not calling the partial correctly. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Im on gmaps4rails 1.5.2 and am having this same issue. just wanted to update you that it seems like this bug is still floating around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question, I realize the problem is on `gmaps4rails` side.

I've just pushed a fix on github, could you try it please?

Comment: Ta for the quick turn around .... but in frustration I've dropped back to standard helpers :(. I'm sure I'll get around to trying it in the next few days again though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried manually editing the gem myself and adding in the prefix forward slash but it didn't help. As I said I've gone back to standard helpers for the moment and I can't verify the fix but I have a feeling it is not correct.

Comment: as far as i can see this is still an issue, anyone?